# Issue Regarding using the Twilio SMS Api in India

Tags: twilio, sms-gateway

Twilio cannot send SMS if the Number is Registered as a Do-Not-Disturb number.However this can be solved
by following the link here: http://ndnc.in/start-calls

The instructions says to send an SMS to 1909 with the body as START n.
where n happens to one of the following:

```
1.Banking/Insurance/Financial products/credit cards
2.Real Estate
3.Education
4.Health
5.Consumer goods and automobiles
6.Communication/Broadcasting/Entertainment/IT
7.Tourism and Leisure
```

The problem is I don't know in which category Twilio falls under.My guess would be 6.But I dont know for sure.
Has anyone faced a similar problem?

I am aware that I can send an STOP 0 to the same number but then again that would start telemarketing calls from all categories,which I don't want.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to send an SMS to a do-not-disturb number?

Comment: Did you solve it? I am facing the same problem and looking for a work around. I basically want to send OTP's.