# Can I use an US number in Twilio in India?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I am just starting to use Twilio. If i use the default US number, can I send message in India?
Using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You should be able to send messages to India using a US Twilio number. There are a few notes and caveats here though.

- If you are just starting with Twilio and have not upgraded your account yet, you can only send SMS messages to numbers that you have verified with Twilio
- Messages sent to India from a regular Twilio number count as promotional messages and have the following restrictions:

  1. Can’t send same message from same international number to same destination number within 20 mins.
  2. Marketing messages should be sent between 9 AM to 9 PM local time.
  3. Sender ID for international number will be replaced with XX-NNNNNN (2 letters followed by 6 numbers).

More details on the restrictions of sending to India is available here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices

Finally, [using Python to send SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages?code-sample=code-send-a-message-with-an-image-url&code-language=py&code-sdk-version=6.x) is definitely possible.

I recommend you install the [Twilio helper library for Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python). Then the code you need looks like:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# put your own credentials here
account_sid = "you_account_sid"
auth_token = "your_auth_token"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

client.messages.create(
    to=TO_NUMBER,
    from_=YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
    body="Hello from Twilio!")
```

Comment: Fantastic! Would you mind marking the answer as correct so that other people can see that it worked easily? Thanks!

Comment: @philnash I'm getting the `error code 30004` when I send an sms to some numbers. From here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825408/issue-regarding-using-the-twilio-sms-api-in-india  it seems that unsubscribing the number from Do-Not-Disturb will also not work. Can you please confirm?

Comment: By default [messages sent from Twilio numbers are "promotional" so will be blocked and receive the 30004 error if the number you are sending to is on the DND registry](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices). You might be able to register the number as a "transactional" number, please get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to see if they can sort that out for you.